# Linux / Ubuntu command similar to Windows cmd "start"?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line

From cmd on windows, you can type "start filename" and an action will be taken based on the programs associated with the type of the file. EXEs will launch, JPEGs will have an associated file viewer opened, etc..

Is there a way to do this on Linux / Ubuntu?

Comment: You should probably ask this question on http://superuser.com instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `xdg-open`.

Comment: and for oldest distrib with gnome - gnome-open